# How to convert a vector<char*> to a vector<string>/string

Tags: c++, stl, vector

We have a legacy method that returns a `vector` of char pointers i.e., `vector<char *>`.
Now, I need to process only strings (`std::string`). How can I do this?

This question may sound simple, but I run into couple of websites which depicted that these sort of considerations might lead to memory leaks.

Now, I either want to get a `vector<string>` or even a string without any memory leaks. How can I do this?

Comment: There's nothing inherently leaky about using vectors, except that they're relatively more memory-expensive while alive. Just use the regular vector operations and destruct it when you're done. char* can easily be converted to a proper c++ string using the string library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, depending on the performance requirements, you could just construct a `std::string` as needed. Like this:

```
for(std::vector<char*>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    std::string s = *it;

    // do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The conversion is quite straightforward:

```
std::vector<char*> ugly_vector = get_ugly_vector();
std::vector<std::string> nice_vector(ugly_vector.begin(), ugly_vector.end());
```

Once you've done that, though, you still need to make sure that the objects pointed to by the pointers in `ugly_vector` are correctly destroyed.  How you do that depends on the legacy code you are utilizing.

Comment: Is the vector constructor calling the string constructor behind the operation?

Comment: You beat me to it. That's a trick I like for converting argv[]

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc); // very handy`

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::copy`:

```
using namespace std;
vector<char*> v_input;
...
// fill v_input
...
vector<string> v_output;

v_output.resize(v_input.size());
copy(v_input.begin(), v_input.end(), v_output.begin());
```