# How to convert a vector<string> to a vector<char*>

Tags: c++, stl, char, stdvector

This is the opposite of [How to convert a vector<char*> to a vector<string>/string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900780/2743307) question.

I have some legacy routine which works with `vector<char*>` so I need to transform my `vector<string>`.

Here is what I come out with:

```
std::vector<char*> charVec(strVec.size(),nullptr);
for (int i=0; i<strVec.size();i++) {
    charVec[i]= new char(strVec[i].size()+1); 
    charVec[i][strVec[i].copy(charVec[i], strVec[i].size())] = '\0';
}
```

Is this correct?

Is there a better way to implement it?

---

p.s. of course at the end I have:

```
for (int i=0; i<strVec.size();i++) {
    delete charVec[i];
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you have a question? looks like you already have it implemented

Comment: It depends if the new vector needs to own it's strings or it just needs a temporary view of the strings in the other vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A faster way of doing this is

```
std::vector<const char*> charVec(strVec.size(),nullptr);
for (int i=0; i<strVec.size();i++) {
    charVec[i]= strVec[i].c_str();
}
```

and then using the resulting vector.   This will save a lot of time on memory allocation for large sets of data.

Comment: Your result vector must be `std::vector<const char*>`. `const char*` is not assignable to `char*`

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my answer.   I always forget that c_str returns a const pointer.

Comment: c_str() life time doesn't allow you to do this I think?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you allocating new buffer for your strings? You are passing a `vector` of character pointers to a function and finally deleting allocated buffers. It means these buffers are temporary and there is no need to allocate memory for them as far as source `vector`(`vector<string>`) exist.

You can easily do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
std::vector<const char*> vec2;

vec2.resize(vec1.size(), nullptr);

std::transform(std::begin(vec1), std::end(vec1), std::begin(vec2), [&](const std::string& str)
{
    return str.c_str();
});
```

Comment: Or you could replace `vec2.resize()` with `vec2.reserve()` and then use `std::back_inserter(vec2)` as the output iterator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of Course, good point. I had forgotten `std::back_inserter`. Thanks for remind.

Answer (score 4):

Your `new` statement looks wrong.  You want to allocate an array of `char` long enough to hold the string.  You're allocating a single `char` whose value is the length of the string.  I'm surprised you didn't get compiler warnings about that.

Try this:

```
std::vector<char*> charVec;
for (const auto &str : strVec) {
  char *charStr = new char[str.size() + 1];
  std::strcpy(charStr, str.c_str());
  charVec.push_back(charStr); 
}
```

The only drawback here is that, if one of the strings has embedded null characters, nothing beyond those will be copied.  But I suspect that a function which takes a vector of `char *` almost certainly doesn't care about that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use [string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to get the [c](/questions/tagged/c) string out of a std::string. Read more in [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Or you could just modify a bit the body of the function, but only you know if this is worth it.

---

Of course as ssell mentions in the comments, keep in mind that with this approach you need not to destroy your strings when you handle them! It's a trade-off, you avoid the copy (so cool), but you need to be careful not reading junk (in case you delete your strings)!

Comment: I would not recommend `std::string::c_str` as it isn't safe. If any of his original `std::string` objects are destroyed, the `char*` string will become invalid. It is better to copy over the data as he does in his question and others do in their answers. See [What is std::string::c_str() lifetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime).

Comment: @ssell good point, but I wouldn't go with the "do not touch" directive, I would like more the use with caution, I will update!

Comment: If he has strict control over the scope, then your answer is the most straight-forward. Just wanted to warn about the potential dangers.

Answer (score 0):

**vector < string > to vector < const char* > : use c_str()**

```
std::vector<const char*> charVec(strVec.size(), nullptr);
for (int i=0; i<strVec.size(); i++) {
    charVec[i] = strVec[i].c_str();
}
```

**vector < string > to vector < char* > : use &x[0]**

```
std::vector<char*> charVec(strVec.size(), nullptr);
for (int i=0; i<strVec.size(); i++) {
    charVec[i] = &strVec[i][0];
}
```

Refs: [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)